# How can I run Doccano as the root user without knowing my root password on EC2?

Tags: root, webserver, amazon-ec2

I use [Doccano](https://github.com/doccano/doccano) on an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu 22.04.

To run Doccano, I use `doccano webserver --port 8000`.

But now I'd like to have Doccano serve its webpages on port 80. [Therefore](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/753855/16704), I have to run Doccano  as root.

How can I run doccano as the root user without knowing my root password on EC2?

---

I tried

```
(doccanopy310) ubuntu@ip-172-30-33-321:~$ sudo doccano webserver --port 80
sudo: doccano: command not found
```

and

```
(doccanopy310) ubuntu@ip-172-30-33-321:~$ su
Password:
```

I don't know the root password in this EC2 instance. I don't have any AWS admin right on it: I was simply given the IP + the .pem file to SSH to it.

---

Another way to reproduce this issue is using the `http.server` in Python 3 (or `SimpleHTTPServer` in Python 2):

```
python -m http.server 80
```

will yield:

```
(doccanopy310) ubuntu@ip-172-30-33-321:~$ sudo python -m http.server 80
sudo: python: command not found
```

Comment: `sudo -s` with your own password may give you a root shell

Comment: @roaima thanks good point, I don't know any user/root passwords :( I SSHed with a .pem file.

Comment: You can use `sudo` - it failed to find `doccano` so it certainly tried. Maybe `sudo -s` works without a password. Or maybe `sudo bash`

Comment: @roaima you're right, that worked, thanks that's a great idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reddit user [a2jeeper](https://www.reddit.com/user/a2jeeper) [pointed me](https://redd.it/15ow9ou) to the correct answer: one needs to indicate the full path of `doccano` or `http.server`. One may use the command `which` to find the full path.

Example with `doccano`:

```
(doccanopy310) ubuntu@ip-172-30-33-321:~$ which doccano
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/doccanopy310/bin/doccano
(doccanopy310) ubuntu@ip-172-30-33-321:~$ sudo /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/doccanopy310/bin/doccano webserver --port 80
[2023-08-12 07:07:32 +0000] [47600] [INFO] [django_drf_filepond.apps::ready::61] App init: no django-storages backend configured, using default (local) storage backend if set, otherwise you need to manage file storage independently of this app.
[2023-08-12 07:07:32 +0000] [47600] [WARNING] [django_drf_filepond.apps::ready::69] Filepond app init: Creating file store directory </root/doccano/media>...
Starting server with port 80.
[2023-08-12 07:07:32 +0000] [47600] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2023-08-12 07:07:32 +0000] [47600] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:80 (47600)
[2023-08-12 07:07:32 +0000] [47600] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-08-12 07:07:32 +0000] [47601] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 47601
[2023-08-12 07:07:32 +0000] [47602] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 47602
[2023-08-12 07:07:33 +0000] [47603] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 47603
[2023-08-12 07:07:33 +0000] [47604] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 47604
[2023-08-12 07:07:33 +0000] [47605] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 47605
```

Note that if one runs `sudo /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/doccanopy310/bin/doccano webserver --port 80`, one needs to run the following:

```
sudo /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/doccanopy310/bin/doccano init
sudo /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/doccanopy310/bin/doccano createuser --username admin --password pass
sudo /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/doccanopy310/bin/doccano webserver --port 80
```

and in another terminal:

```
sudo /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/doccanopy310/bin/doccano task
```

Otherwise one can't connect with the `admin` user.

---

Example with `http.server` :

```
(doccanopy310) ubuntu@ip-172-30-33-321:~$ which python
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/doccanopy310/bin/python
(doccanopy310) ubuntu@ip-172-30-33-321:~$ sudo /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/doccanopy310/bin/python -m http.server 80
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 80 (http://0.0.0.0:80/) ...
91.12.100.231 - - [12/Aug/2023 06:52:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```